# Trouble Implementing Array Based Queue

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, queue

I am working on homework for a class. We have to implement an array based circular queue. I am having trouble figuring out the algorithm for determining if the queue is full and empty. Below is the C++ source file that I am working in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include "circularQueue.h"
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
circularQueue<Type>::circularQueue(const int & capacity) {

assert (capacity >= 0);
this-> capacity = capacity;
front = 0;
rear = capacity-1;
array = new Type[capacity];
}

template <class Type>
circularQueue<Type>::~circularQueue() {

delete [] array;
}

template <class Type>
void circularQueue<Type>::add(Type value){

    if (!isFull())
    {
        rear = (rear + 1) % capacity;
        array[rear] = value;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "The queue is full, cannot add value." << endl;
    }
}

template <class Type>
void circularQueue<Type>::remove(){

    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        front = (front + 1) % capacity;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot delete from and empty queue." << endl;
    }
}

template <class Type>
Type circularQueue<Type>::getFront() {

    return array[front];
}

template <class Type>
Type circularQueue<Type>::getRear() {

    return array[rear];
}

template <class Type>
int circularQueue<Type>::size() {

int size;

    if (front > rear)
    {
        size = (capacity + rear) - front;
    }

    else
    {
        size = rear - front;
    }

    return size;
}

template <class Type>
bool circularQueue<Type>::isEmpty() {

bool empty = false;

    if (front == rear) //if the front and rear are not pointing to the same index, its not full
    {
        empty = true;
    }

    return empty;
}

template <class Type>
bool circularQueue<Type>::isFull(){

bool full = true;

   if (size() != capacity) // if size = capacity, queue is full;
   {
        full = false;
   }

    return full;
}

/* Test Procedure */
int main() {

circularQueue<int> queue(3); //create a queue that can hold 3 items(int)
queue.add(1); //add the value 1 to the queue [1]
queue.add(2); //add the value 2 to the queue [2, 1]
queue.add(3); //add the value 3 to the queue [3, 2, 1]
queue.add(4); // shouldn't work capacity is 3 trying to store 4 values
queue.remove(); //remove the element at the front[3, 2] front should point to 2

cout << "The front is: " << queue.getFront() << endl;
cout << "The rear is: " << queue.getRear() << endl;
cout << "The number of elements in the queue is: " << queue.size() <<     endl;
}
```

When I run the program this following output is produced:

Cannot delete from and empty queue.

The front is: 4

The rear is: 4

The number of elements in the queue is: 0

This leads me to believe that I have errors in my logic for isFull() isEmpty() and possible my add() and remove() functions.

Comment: You probably want to explicitly track the size in a member variable.  Rear == front has the problem that it is likely ambiguous.  Rear == front would likely be true when it is empty, so if it is also going to be your full condition too then you something else to disambiguate, which is one reason why I recommend explicitly tracking the size.

Comment: @jschultz410 we are not allowed to keep track of the size explicitly unfortunately

Comment: Shouldn't `rear` be equal to `front` when the queue is created?

Comment: @AntonSavin not according to the way my professor wants us to implement it. i have rear to capacity - 1 because that would be the last element in the array

Comment: @ZackHerbert so immediately after creation `size()` won't return `0`.

Comment: i think in your add method this "rear = (rear + 1) % capacity;" should be like this rear = (front + size())% capacity; its right in your remove though

Comment: @AntonSavin so this problem is part of an implementation that is in our textbook. I copied the constructor and some of the methods that are provided for us. The only difference is that there is a count variable in the constructor and is used to keep track of the size when you add and remove and element. The professor doesn't want us to use that method because it is too "easy".

Comment: Here's an issue: when you initially construct the Q you have front = 0, rear = cap - 1, but !isFull().  Then if you add(), rear will wrap around to 0.  Then size() = 0 and isEmpty() is true, which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @ZackHerbert first of all, you should clearly mark which code is provided by the professor and which code is written by you. Either initialization or `size()` are done wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think you want to start out with `front = rear = 0`, which implies isEmpty(), but the deeper problem is that using front to indicate the first element and rear to indicate the last element doesn't really work.  Because imagine if we now add() one element.  getFront() and getRear() now return two different elements even though the Q only contains one element.

Comment: I'd change front to be begin and rear to be end.  Begin is the index of the front of the list, unless it's empty, while end is the index one past the last element in the list.  begin == end implies the list is empty.  size() == end - begin, when end >= begin.  Final tip: make the array one element bigger than the capacity of elements you will allow in the Q.  This way you eliminate the ambiguousness of when begin == end meaning either its empty or its full.  If you make the underlying array 1 element bigger than capacity and do all your modulus arithmetic based on capacity + 1, that'll work.